# ¿ Como añadir varios diccionarios dentro de otro?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tengo un diccionario con la llave "dic" y otros dos diccionarios con la llave "a" y "b".

```
@{@"a":@{@"datoa1":1,@"datoa2":2}};
@{@"b":@{@"datob1":1,@"datob2":2}};
```

¿ Como agregar los diccionarios con algún método al diccionario padre pero sin sus llaves de inicio ?

```
{
    dic = {
        datoa1 = 1;
        datoa2 = 2;

        datob1 = 1;
        datob2 = 2;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Deberías crear un diccionario mutable (`NSMutableDictionary`) en el que agregas los elementos, sería algo así:

```
NSDictionary *a = @{@"a":@{@"datoa1":1,@"datoa2":2}};
NSDictionary *b = @{@"b":@{@"datob1":1,@"datob2":2}};
NSMutableDictionary *tmp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:(a.count + b.count)];
[tmp addEntriesFromDictionary:a[@"a"]];
[tmp addEntriesFromDictionary:b[@"b"]];
NSDictionary *dic = @{ @"dic": tmp };
```

**Nota**: Si ambos diccionarios, `a` y `b` tienen la misma *key*, entonces en el diccionario final queda el último valor que hayas agregado (en el ejemplo sería el de `b`).

[Documentación de `addEntriesFromDictionary:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutabledictionary/1411035-addentriesfromdictionary?language=objc)